# How do I get a UTF-8 string out of an MD5 digest?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use an API that requires an MD5 hash to be sent in UTF-8 format.

Problem is, I can't find any way to actually make that happen.

```
require 'digest/md5'
api_sig = Digest::MD5.digest "api_key=blahblahblah"
puts api_sig

>> Decode error: not UTF-8
```

So I try `force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)`. Same error. `inspect`, `to_s`, nothing gives me what I want.

How can I get a UTF-8 string representing an MD5 digest of another string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `Digest::MD5.hexdigest "api_key=blahblahblah"`

The documentation of this is very poor, but you can find a lackluster explanation here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/Class.html#method-c-hexdigest